# How to efficiently put mongodb query document to an array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I am new to Mongodb, and met many problems caused by the amount of data. 
Currently I have a Mongodb collection which contains 10^9 points' coordinate in following format (Mongodb GeoJSON format):

```
{
    "location": 
    {
        "x": 15.2345,
        "y": 100.3456,    
    }          
    "Height": 25.2342
}
```

Now I need to query 10^6 nearby points of a given location. I tried `find($near)` command provided by Mongodb GeoSpatial Index, and it is quite efficient. But what it returns is just a cursor, and I have to iterate all document of this cursor using a `for` loop to obtain an array (say numpy array), which cost a lot of time.

I cannot find any other approach from Mongodb documents. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to query data into an array? If not, should I organize these points in other format?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try Monary, which directly translates MongoDB's BSON data to NumPy arrays:

http://monary.readthedocs.io/